# Insecure Security rules for Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I always get the mail about my Cloud Firestore security rules being insecure.

> Every user can read the whole database

But I don't get it? These are my rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /users/{userID} {
            allow read;
            allow write: if request.auth != null;
        }
        match /users/{userId}/wishlists/{restOfPath=**} {
            allow read,write: if request.auth != null;
        }
    }
}
```

`users` should be readable for everyone but everything else should be restricted to authorized users only. What am I missing here?

Comment: I think this is just a warning from Firestore, it is recommended to try to avoid such scenarios when you need to open access to your db to all users. You can read more about rules [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/insecure-rules#open_access)

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised by the "allow read;" line. You can replace it with "allow read: if true;"

And it is safer to start your rules file with:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;  // General rule that protects access to documents not covered by the next rules
    }
```

> ```
> }
> ```